# How can I read a variable from flask with javascript as an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, flask, jinja2

I am using flask in order to deploy some variables to html and javascript:

```
prob_home_win = round(100 * prediction2[0,2],1)    
prob_draw_game = round(100 * prediction2[0,1],1)  
prob_away_win = round(100 * prediction2[0,0],1)    

array_total = [prob_home_win, prob_draw_game, prob_away_win]

return render_template('index.html', array_total = array_total, user_image = full_filename)
```

then I read the variable with javascript:

```
var array_total = '{{ array_total }}';
```

but when I read it

```
console.log('array total =', array_total)
console.log('type of array_total =', typeof array_total)
```

it tells me that it is a string, which is not what I want, I want it to read it as an array... how can I make the variable to be read as an array?

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried removing the quotes i.e. `var array_total = {{ array_total }}`?

Comment: yes and still don't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the variable is inside the quotation. But you can't remove the quotation, if you do, it will through syntax error.

You can use `JSON.parse`

```
array_total = JSON.parse('{{ array_total|tojson|safe }}')
```

Comment: it displays VM20:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: remove |tojson and try.